# npm installation error when installing package libxml

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, libxml2

I am trying to install the package libxml with the command

> npm i libxml

Unfortunately, I get the following error which I dont really understand.

```
% npm i libxml                                                                                          
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/smo/Documents/adep2/adep-export-tool-js/node_modules/libxml
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c ./build.sh
npm ERR! ./build.sh: line 8: node-waf: command not found
npm ERR! ./build.sh: line 9: node-waf: command not found
npm ERR! cp: build/Release/o3.node: No such file or directory

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/smo/.npm/_logs/2021-06-14T12_12_32_467Z-debug.log
```

If someone could explain at least explain the error to me it would be pretty helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. This happened because I was using the wrong node version. The package libxml reuires to the node version 14.x.x. and mine was 16.3.0